# Store zip file to Core data entity like a attribute

Tags: ios

I'm work in my application with Core data and want save my zip file to core data entity. Please, tell me is possible and how is possible do

Comment: It's bad practice to save files in Core Data. Save the file in a folder inside the documents folder and save the (relative) URL in Core Data

Answer (score 0):

As vadian suggest its a bad practice to store file to core data, if you still wants to save it.

Convert the zip file to data and store the data to Core Data.

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: <file_path>] //Objective C
Data.init(contentsOf: <file_path>) //Swift
```

And Core Data supports the Data attribute, so you will be able to save the data.